# Python detecting when a key is pressed in game

Tags: python, keyboard

So I'm trying to get a Python script to detect if I've pressed insert and if I have it should print the clipboard to a file.

I've got most of it working but it seems the game eats up my keyboard detection.

I currently have:

```
keyboard.add_hotkey('k',writeToFile,args=[])
```

using the keyboard module, but it does nothing when in game. Outside the game it works fine.

Comment: Is "the keyboard module" [this third-party library](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) or one of the other ones with the same name? Also, does "the game" mean you're using PyGame, or curses, or something else that has its own interaction with the keyboard different from normal command-line apps?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/ ye it's this library. It's the game diablo II

Comment: Oh, I get it; you're trying to send keys to a game that's running separately, not send keys within a game of your own. Sorry for being obtuse. (You should edit the link into the question, though.)

Comment: Also, I assume you're on Windows (7, 8, or 10), and running the Windows version of the game natively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [the README](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) says:

> Other applications, such as some games, may register hooks that swallow all key events. In this case `keyboard` will be unable to report events.

If `keyboard` can't report the events, it can't use them to trigger a hotkey.

It *may* be possible to get around it by just waiting until the game has started, and only then starting your script. If there's no way to tab out of the game without quitting, of course, this is obviously a non-starter—but even if you can do that, it still may not work.

And if not, you just can't hook keyboard events with a global event hook. Which means there's nothing `keyboard` can do for you.

But, since you're dealing with an 18-year-old game here, there might be a workaround: You may be able to run the game inside an emulator or virtual machine, smoothly enough to be perfectly playable. If so, the game should only be able to globally hook events inside the emulator/VM, not on the real system, so your hook may be able to catch events first. (You may still need to run your script last, or you may need to configure your Wine/VMware/whatever settings, but it may just work out of the box.)

Comment: Alright there is no python library the would allow me to record the hooks as they come up in the game?

Comment: @louise If the game is swallowing those events, there's nothing any library could do to change that. Either you have to get your hook in front of them (which is a matter of doing one of the things I suggested in the answer, none of which are guaranteed to work, but they might be worth trying), or your hook won't do anything. There might be _other_ ways to intercept things before they even get to the global hooks queue in the first place, but I suspect that would probably involve something like a custom USB driver, which wouldn't be a Python solution.